# React: empty placeholder div gets re-rendered and thereby removes children (asynchr attached chart)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, single-page-application, dc.js, react-grid-layout

I am working on a widget dashboard which has DC.JS charts as content for each widget.

Widgets are created/ removed using **react-grid-layout** which creates an empty placeholder node like this:

```
<div id={"content_" + this.props.id} className="widgetContent"> /* chart is later drawn here */ </div>)
```

DC.JS later selects the div by Id and attaches its SVG chart as a child.

The problem is that for some events (like toggling static or changing Ids of the widgets), react re-renders the widgets and thereby "overwrites" the existing charts (children) with a brand new empty placeholder div as above.

My question is if that issue can be solved by React-techniques (*can I prevent a div from ever being re-rendered*?) or if this is an issue with the library itself.

Very similar code can be found [here](https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout/blob/fbb7bd2b007d762572b87d1a82e3e6f2b318ea3b/test/examples/6-dynamic-add-remove.jsx). The code in action is [here](https://strml.github.io/react-grid-layout/examples/6-dynamic-add-remove.html). Imagine the snippet line above (the empty chart placeholder where a chart is attached later) in [line 44](https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout/blob/fbb7bd2b007d762572b87d1a82e3e6f2b318ea3b/test/examples/6-dynamic-add-remove.jsx#L44).

Answer (score 1):

The common solution here is to wrap this chart in a component where `shouldComponentUpdate` is set to false. That way react will never alter the element which your charting library modifies. An example wrapper component can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/alexeisavca/d4ff175fd16c93c8785d) (including below)

```
var React = require('react/addons');
var ReactIgnore = {
    displayName: 'ReactIgnore',
    shouldComponentUpdate (){
        return false;
    },

    render (){
        return React.Children.only(this.props.children);
    }
};

module.exports = {
    Class: ReactIgnore,
    Component: React.createClass(ReactIgnore)
};
```